# Is this inequality related to this integral correct?

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $\alpha >0, 1/3 >\beta>0, T>0$, $h \in [0,T]$. In [Cerrai, Sandra. "Normal deviations from the averaged motion for some reaction–diffusion equations with fast oscillating perturbation." Journal de mathématiques pures et appliquées 91.6 (2009): 614-647.] the following integral is estimated at P.641 as follows:
\begin{aligned}
    \int_{0}^{\alpha h} r^{-2 \beta} e^{-2 r} d r \leqslant c_{T}(h \alpha \wedge 1)^{1-2 \beta}
\end{aligned}
for some $C=C_T>0$ constant independent of $\alpha, h$. Here the notation $h \alpha \wedge 1$ means $h (\alpha \wedge 1)$ where $\wedge$ is the "minimum" (this can be seen at p.630 when the author applies Lemma 4.2 to estimate $I_{\epsilon,2}^n$ since an $h^{1+\rho}$ comes out of the series while $\alpha_k \wedge 1=1$ for $k$ big enough since here $\alpha_k=k^2$ ).

Now is the estimate correct? I don't think so as by a change of variable
\begin{aligned}
    I:=\int_{0}^{\alpha h} r^{-2 \beta} e^{-2 r} d r =  h^{1-2\beta}  \int_{0}^{\alpha } \tau^{-2  \beta} e^{-2 h \tau} d \tau
\end{aligned}
Now if $\alpha <1$ I get $I \leq C (h\alpha)^{1-2\beta} $ with $C$ independent of $\alpha, h$.
If $\alpha >1$ instead in order to get a constant $C$ independent of $\alpha$ (which can be big)
\begin{aligned}
    I & \leq   h^{1-2\beta}  \int_{0}^{\infty } \tau^{-2  \beta} e^{-2 h \tau} d \tau= \int_{0}^{\infty} r^{-2 \beta} e^{-2 r} d r \leq C
\end{aligned}
but then here I lose the $h^{1-2\beta}$  in front. Do you see other ways to estimate this term keeping $h^{1-2\beta}$  in front?

So I think the correct estimate should be
\begin{aligned}
    \int_{0}^{\alpha h} r^{-2 \beta} e^{-2 r} d r \leqslant c_{T}((h \alpha) \wedge 1)^{1-2 \beta}
\end{aligned}
do you agree? but then at p. 630 the author could not proceed as said before, right?

Comment: P.630, Do you notice $h^{1+\rho}\alpha_k^{(1+\rho)(n+1)/2 - n} = \alpha_k^{(1+\rho)(n-1)/2 - n}(h\alpha_k)^{1 + \rho} $?

Comment: yes but at p630 the author has $(h \alpha_h)^{n}$ not $(h \alpha_h)^{1+\rho}$. Where did you take that?

Comment: Perhaps take some bound. Anyway, based on this, I think $h \alpha \wedge 1$ means $(h \alpha) \wedge 1$.